# 502 Bad Gateway for Jenkins with nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, jenkins, vps, bad-gateway

I have a VPS with nginx. gitlab, phpmyadmin is already running with certbots https. Now I want to add jenkins. I changed its port to 8090 for not colidating with gitlabs 8080 port. I checked each ones status and all services are running.

```
    upstream jenkins {
  keepalive 32;
  server localhost:8090 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    server_name build.example.de;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/jenkins_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/jenkins_error.log;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/build.example.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/build.example.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
     proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     proxy_redirect http:// https://;
     proxy_pass http://jenkins;

     # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_request_buffering off;
     proxy_buffering off; # Required for HTTP-based CLI to work over SSL

     # workaround for https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45651
     add_header 'X-SSH-Endpoint' 'build.example.de:50022' always;
    }

}

server {
    if ($host = build.example.de) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;

    server_name build.example.de;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Im always getting the error:

```
[error] 8441#8441: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 88.65.0.115, server: build.example.de, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:8090/", host: "build.example.de"


Jul 26 16:32:10 v22018076557869542 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time...
Jul 26 16:32:10 v22018076557869542 jenkins[24446]: Error: Unable to access jarfile jenkins-cli.jar
Jul 26 16:32:10 v22018076557869542 jenkins[24446]: Correct java version found
Jul 26 16:32:10 v22018076557869542 jenkins[24446]:  * Starting Jenkins Automation Server jenkins
Jul 26 16:32:10 v22018076557869542 su[24520]: Successful su for jenkins by root
Jul 26 16:32:10 v22018076557869542 su[24520]: + ??? root:jenkins
Jul 26 16:32:10 v22018076557869542 su[24520]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user jenkins by (u
Jul 26 16:32:10 v22018076557869542 su[24520]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user jenkins
Jul 26 16:32:11 v22018076557869542 jenkins[24446]:    ...done.
Jul 26 16:32:11 v22018076557869542 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
```

What Im doing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your request is redirected to upstream: "**https**://127.0.0.1:8090/", while it should be simple **http**, try to remove **proxy_redirect http:// https://;**

Comment: can you make a request to jenkins locally just to make sure it's working, like this `curl http://127.0.0.1:8090`

Comment: curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8090: Connection refused
this is the output

Comment: that means your Jenkins doesn't listen on this port, how did you changed the port ?

Comment: oh wow okay.. well I changed the $HTTP_PORT variable in /etc/default/jenkins and restarted jenkins also..

Comment: this is the last line of the above mentioned jenkins file: java -jar jenkins-cli.jarJENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --httpListenAddress=$HTTP_PORT"

Comment: status of the service: Active: active (exited)

Comment: Try to edit jenkins.xml file located in jenkins home directory, and replace `–httpPort=8080` with desired one, then restart service

Comment: I cannot find the jenkins.xml. I have ubuntu as OS on my vps

Comment: did you changed the variable in the last line or it value like HTTP_PORT=8090, this should be located a couple of lines above

Comment: I added this to the args:  --httpListenAddress=$HTTP_PORT" and changed the value of HTTP_PORT

Comment: can you attach this file ?

Comment: Im getting another error on viewing the status of jenkins. Please check the fquestion. I edited it

Comment: ow, does jenkins user have permission to access jenkins-cli.jar ?

Comment: I even cant find this file :/

Comment: I would restore original /etc/default/jenkins file, then disable gitlab service for a moment just to check that jenkins is running without problems, most probably it a typo or misconfig in that file

Comment: what I could do is executing the jenkins.war file and isntall everything. Created admin account and installed jenkins. but I needed to quit and wanted to start jenkins by service but it says again that it cannot access jenkins.jar file

Comment: my only problem is I cannot locate the jenkins-cli.jar file on my server. Where can I find it?

Comment: If Jenkins is not running, run this command -
```sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins restart```